# Flutter TextFormField causing delay while navigating

Tags: flutter, forms, performance, dart

I'm building flutter app in which i have a LoginView with 2 TextFormField, when i navigate from route1 to LoginView it takes a almost 1 second delay to navigate to LoginView... It happens only once when i launch app.  if i pop from LoginView and then navigate again it goes all smooth. when i comment TextFormField on LoginView it goes smooth.

I'm using stacked architecture with stacked services for navigation

here is the custom widget form TextFormField...

```
class CommonTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final String? labelText;
  final String? fieldHeading;
  final Color? fillcolor;
  final TextStyle? textStyle;
  final Color? bordercolor;
  final bool? isTextHidden;
  final String? hintText;
  final String? prefixIcon;
  final bool? togglePassword;
  final int? maxLength;
  final int? maxlines;
  final void Function()? toggleFunction;
  final String? toggleIcon;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;
  final void Function()? prefixIconTap;
  final Function(String)? onChanged;
  final FocusNode? focus;
  final double? prefixIconHeihgt;

  const CommonTextField(
      {super.key,
      this.controller,
      this.textStyle,
      this.maxlines = 1,
      this.bordercolor,
      this.labelText,
      this.fillcolor,
      this.hintText,
      this.isTextHidden,
      this.prefixIcon,
      this.onChanged,
      this.togglePassword = false,
      this.toggleFunction,
      this.toggleIcon,
      this.keyboardType,
      this.maxLength,
      this.prefixIconTap,
      this.fieldHeading,
      this.prefixIconHeihgt,
      this.focus});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      style: TextStyles.body,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      obscureText: isTextHidden ?? false,
      maxLength: maxLength,
      cursorColor: AppConstants.primaryColor,
      focusNode: focus,
      keyboardType: keyboardType ?? TextInputType.text,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      maxLines: maxlines,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        counterText: "",
        suffixIcon: toggleIcon != null
            ? GestureDetector(
                onTap: toggleFunction,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppConstants.space12),
                    child: SvgAsset(src: toggleIcon)))
            : null,
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 0.2,
            color: AppConstants.primaryColor,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(AppConstants.space12),
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 0.2,
            color: AppConstants.primaryColor,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(AppConstants.space12),
          ),
        ),
        hintText: hintText,
        fillColor: AppConstants.whiteColor.withOpacity(0.1),
        filled: true,
        hintStyle: TextStyles.body,
        contentPadding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 11.0, horizontal: 18.0),
        labelText: labelText,
        labelStyle: TextStyles.body,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but it happens only once, when app starts

Comment: This seems like some kind of loading mechanism or initialization, and the call to the function is synchronously and probably the issue. Please add the `LoginView` widget.

Comment: this is what i was assuming but there is not any logical work done yet, its only UI built yet with simple form validation... nothing else

Comment: Try to build your app in release mode and see if you are still experiencing these performance issues.

Comment: it's working fine in release mode

Comment: Then it is some overhead due to the debugging and can be disregarded. Always test the performance in profile mode. (https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/ui-performance)